# Characters are being re-encoded in control panel

Tags: control-panel

I am having a strange issue.

I have the latest version of EE 2.5.3 installed.

If I update any text inside of a text area in the control panel (including templates, a template for an extension like Better Meta), certain characters are automatically converted to html encoded tags. For example, `<` becomes `&lt;`

Working from flat-file templates, this isn't an issue. This only occurs when editing in the control panel.

Any ideas? Here is a screenshot: http://f.cl.ly/items/3u2Q190k3g4506052p0d/wtf.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to track this one down.

I came across this post - http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/168189/

It looks like if `$config['global_xss_filtering']` is set to `TRUE`, all characters are automatically encoded on GET or POST.

Setting it to `FALSE` has corrected the issue.